# loop with BeautifulSoup to web scrape multiple pages by timestamps

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrive the day temperature of a local weather site.
I built this loop using BeautifulSoup.
Unfortunately the loop breaks after the first round.

this is my code and the result:
code:

```
#coding: latin-1

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

# create a file zam-data.txt
# seperated with komma 

f = open('zamg-data.txt','w')

# start webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")

#loop through month and days

for m in range(1,13):
    for d in range (1, 32):

        # was the last day in a month 
        if (m==2 and d>28):
            break
        elif (m in [4,6,9,11] and d>30):
            break

        #open zamg site

        timestamp = '2019' +'-'+ str(m) +'-'+ str(d)
        print("call page of "+timestamp)
        url = "https://www.zamg.ac.at/cms/de/klima/klima-aktuell/klimamonitoring/?param=t&period=period-ymd-"+timestamp
        driver.get(url)

        # extract temprature
        html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        data = soup.find_all(class_='u-txt--big')[1].string
        print(len(data))
        print(data + '...okay')


        # format month for timestamp
        if(len(str(m)) < 2):
            mStamp = '0'+str(m)
        else:
            mStamp = str(m)

        # format day for timestamp
        if(len(str(d)) < 2):
            dStamp = '0'+ str(d)
        else:
            dStamp = str(d)

        # timestamp 
        timestamp = '2019' + mStamp + dStamp

        # write time and value
        f.write(timestamp + ',' + data + '\n')


# data is extracted - close

f.close()
```

my result:

```
➜  weather-app python get-data-02.py
call page of 2019-1-1
5
+3,9 ...okay
call page of 2019-1-2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-data-02.py", line 37, in <module>
    data = soup.find_all(class_='u-txt--big')[1].string
IndexError: list index out of range
➜  weather-app
```

I don't understand what is wrong here. the 2nd page is loaded in the browser but then it breaks
any Ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use this to create a date-array rather than having nested loops: ```import datetime

base = datetime.datetime(2019,1,1).date()
date_list = [base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(365)]``` sorry about the weird indent.

Comment: I think the page takes some time to load. Perhaps using selenium, you can wait until class="u-txt--big" appears in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#coding: latin-1

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import datetime
import time

base = datetime.datetime(2019,1,1).date()
date_list = [base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(365)]


# start webdriver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")

base_url = "https://www.zamg.ac.at/cms/de/klima/klima-aktuell/klimamonitoring/?param=t&period=period-ymd-"

with open('zamg-data.txt','w') as file:
    for dt in date_list:
        timestamp = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        print("call page of "+timestamp)
        url = f"{base_url}{timestamp}"
        driver.get(url)
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=40).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "u-txt--big")))

        # extract temprature
        html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        data = soup.find_all(class_='u-txt--big')[1].string
        print(len(data))
        print(data + '...okay')


        # timestamp 
        timestamp_1 = dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")

        # write time and value
        file.write(timestamp_1 + ',' + data + '\n')
        time.sleep(3)


driver.quit()
print("Done!!!")
```

As someone from the comment section mentioned, you need to make the browser wait till all elements of that class are detected. I've added an explicit time delay after each page load so that the website is not overwhelmed with requests. It is a potential way to get your IP blocked. It's best to always use a context manager, whenever you can.

Comment: okay!  thank you very much. I also tried a time.sleep() after the comment of @Sri.
I see. Thank you very much. I am new into this and will take your advise seriously.